# Pentaho CDE Not generates Dashboards

Tags: java, jsp, pentaho, dashboard

I am newbie to pentaho, trying to built a dashboard to cube developed for mysql db

pentaho ce  version----stable  4.8

cde+cdf+cda version----stable 13.09.10

**I have these layers:**

Wizards;

community data access;

legacy data sources;

Which of the above layers are working i tried olap chart wizard& selector, saiku wizard none worked for me, some show result in preview but not displayed onto dash board.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see a lot more layers in the datasource tab.

Can you try reinstalling ctools ?

Also, check the server logs for initializations issues. From what you describe, it looks as if CDA is not starting up properly.